# Is there any way to get the status of a firebase request?

Tags: swift, firebase, chat

It seems that one of the common Firebase use cases is a chat app so I started playing around with it in that context. I really enjoyed how easy it was to work out auth and get a basic chat up and running. However I got thrown for a loop when I started trying to determine the status of a request and implement timeouts. I'm specifically using Firebase in Swift.

The first status I tried to implement was a "sending" status but because there is no way to know the status of a request, I ended up storing their autogenerated ids in an array and removing them on the complete handler. This isn't horrible but I can think of edge cases such as someone shutting down the app before a sync so I lose my array of messages in the queue but maybe a message hasn't sync'd. Then they restart the app and it's not in the right state as firebase tries to send the message.

Is there any flag in a Firebase database object (a "row"/"document"/"node") that will tell you the data is actually on the server. A complete callback is great but it disappears in the event of an app crash/shutdown mid-request and it still means I have to write my own logic to know if a node is sync'd because the observe callbacks fire before a node is on the server. Is there anything like `node.isSynced`?

The second status I want to implement is a failure status. Let's say a user sends a message and a minute later it hasn't sent because of bad connection. I think it's a pretty bad experience to have the sending status just sitting there so I was hoping to have a "send failed".

I'm hoping that someone who has implemented chat with Firebase can weight in on these two issues. I read the docs thoroughly but am I missing some Firebase paradigm that would make this stuff not feel like I'm going against the Firebase religion?

Comment: What do you mean my *status of a request*? Also, firebase is asynchronous so there should never really be a time the UI is locked. You can handle Firebase errors in the completion closure pretty easily.

Comment: @Jay - Maybe I could clarify the situation a bit further / ask a better question. Let's start here - is there any flag in a Firebase database object (a 
"row"/"document"/"node") that will tell you the data is actually on the server. A complete callback is great but it disappears in the event of an app crash/shutdown mid-request and it still means I have to write my own logic to know if a node is sync'd because the observe callbacks fire before a node is on the server. Is there anything like `node.isSynced`?

Comment: This is good additional info - it would be best to update the actual *question* in this case as it clarifies the question quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting whether a value has been written to the database, you can use completion listener. See Jay's sample here: [Firebase completion listeners in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179186/firebase-completion-listeners-in-swift)

You can definitely do a time-out for certain operations. But a more common approach to show the connection status is to [use Firebase's built-in `.info/connected` path to detect the connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

If you're having problems making either of these work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks Frank! How do listeners work if the app crashes mid request? Won't Firebase try to continue with the request but then I will lose the callback?

Comment: Also you mentioned "You can definitely do a time-out for certain operations" but I don't see it in the docs. Would you mind sharing?

Comment: @Tony Code within a closure runs *after* the data is successfully written to Firebase. The process is (loosely): app writes data->successfully written to server->ok sent back to app->code in closure runs. As you can see, even if the code in the closure blows up, it will not occur until *after* the data is written. Adding a listener (observer) watches for changes within Firebase and aren't directly related to pushing the data to Firebase other than if there is a listener on a note, your app will be notified of that write, which is independent from the code in the completion closure running.

Comment: @Tony I would be interested in a use case - or maybe an example of a scenario where an app would crash mid-request. What kind of request? Can you update your question with more specific data?

Comment: @Jay I'm not referring to a Firebase related crash. Let's say your connection is slow so it takes a few seconds to write. In that few seconds, your app crashes for some other reason. Firebase will be able to recover when the app restarts but your completion handler won't come with it (noting that this may only be true if persistence is enabled, still learning about that). So when your app restarts you'll get the childAdded observation because that's just a local read (from what I understand) but when the node is written, you won't be notified. At least this is what it seems.

Comment: @Tony You may be overthinking this. If an app crashes and is restarted, it will need data from Firebase. Often times that accomplished via a .childAdded event, which in this case, would load all of the data via the .childAdded completion handler. So yes, if the app crashes, and is restarted, the completion handler will be called once for each node (via  .childAdded). This is unrelated to persistence since we are talking about writing to/from the server. i.e. once the app restarts, your data will load and all new data will be sent to the app.

Comment: @Jay Yea but childAdded would be called for data that is not on the server if persistence is enabled. So basically if childAdded is called for data that is not on the server, I need to know that data is not on the server so the user knows it's not yet on the server. Make sense?

Comment: @Tony Persistance is a different topic. The initial question was 'will tell you the data is actually on the server' so the answer and responses have revolved around that. That being said; if and app is in the process of writing data (to server or locally) and crashes, there's no guarantee the data was written. Whether it's a server write or a local write via persistence, a crashing app adds another variable. I think that would be true for any kind of situation where an app crashes during a write cycle. Perhaps another question including concerns about persistence and how that's handled?