# How to store custom object in Firebase with Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm porting an android app and using firebase in android it is possible to save a format in this way. 
How can i do this on Swift? I read that i can store only this kind of data

- NSString
- NSNumber
- NSDictionary
- NSArray

How can I store the obj in atomic operation?
It's correct to store every field of the user object in separate action?

Firebase on Android

```
mDatabaseReferences.child("users").child(user.getUuid()).setValue(user)
```

Comment: There are no custom objects in Firebase, so no, you cannot directly store an object in Firebase. However, you can store an objects properties (strings, dicts, numbers) in Firebase, and if you include functions in your object class, it will 'feel' like you are. However, the question is super vague as it doesn't include the *user* object you are referring to. If you can clarify and update the question, we may be able to help.

Comment: the user has the usual fields. That is name, surname, city etc.
I want to save this object and retrive the data as in Android. If this is not possible, how can i store this all this field in atomic operation? The dictionaries is a good solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally store objects as dictionaries on firebase. If, within my application, I have a User object, and it has properties as such:

```
class User {
var username = ""
var email = ""
var userID = ""
var consecutiveDaysLoggedOn = Int()
}



let newUser = User()
   newUser.username = "LeviYoder"
   newUser.email = "LeviYoder@LeviYoder.com"
   newUser.userID = "L735F802847A-"
   newUser.consecutiveDaysLoggedOn = 1
```

I would just store those properties as a dictionary, and write that dictionary to my firebase database:

```
let userInfoDictionary = ["username" : newUser.username
                           "email" : newUser.email
                           "userID" : newUser.userID
              "consecutiveDaysLoggedOn" : newUser.consecutiveDaysLoggedOn]

let ref = Database.database().reference.child("UserInfo").child("SpecificUserFolder")
//      ref.setValue(userInfoDictionary) { (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in

ref.setValue(userInfoDictionary, withCompletionBlock: { err, ref in
    if let error = err {
        print("userInfoDictionary was not saved: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("userInfoDictionary saved successfully!")
    }
}
```

Does that address your question?

Comment: If i use dictionaries, do i store in atomic operation? Is possible that i save only some field, for example if the user close the app during the store?

Comment: Great answer. If it were me, I would probably take most of that code an include it in the actual user class. So when it's time to write it out, you could just *ref.setValue( someUser.getPropertyDict() )* and the getPropertyDict would bundle up all of the classes properties and return a dictionary to be written out to Firebase. Likewise, reading in a user snapshot, you could pass that to the class to init it  *var someUser = UserClass(initWith: snapshot*

Comment: @a.sarto Almost all Firebase calls have a closure so you can handle errors during a write. See [-setValue:withCompletionBlock:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)setValue:withCompletionBlock:)

Comment: Could you give me an example of the code to write in User class? I'm new to swift and I'm still not very practical

Comment: i've found this example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179186/firebase-completion-listeners-in-swift

I think that it could be good 
@Jay if you think there are better solutions update me.
Thanks for the answers and the tip

Comment: @a.sarto I just added a completion handler to the setValue being executed. Has your question been answered?

Comment: @LeviYoder I edited your answer slightly - the setValue closure wasn't valid so I commented it and added the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

I come with a little extension used to convert a standard SwiftObject in readable dictionnary for FireStore:

```
extension Encodable {
    var toDictionnary: [String : Any]? {
        guard let data =  try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
    }
}
```

For example, in my model:

```
struct Order: Encodable {
    let symbol: String
    let shares: Int
    let price: Float
    let userID: String
}
```

Called with this line:

```
let dictionnary = order.toDictionnary
```

This is the kind of dictionary generated

```
4 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "symbol"
    - value : FP.PAR
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "shares"
    - value : 10
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : "userID"
    - value : fake_id
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    - key : "price"
    - value : 100
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to save a user *object* in Firebase, not how to write a single key: value pair.

Comment: Well, like he said, firebase can store a NSDictionary, that can be a entire object.
Let me me edit the answer.