# check if firebase write operation was successful in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to check if firebase real time write operation was successful in ios?

I am trying to store data to real time database using the following code but it does not work:-

```
//adding the artist inside the generated unique key
    refArtists.child(key!).setValue(data) { (error, dbreference) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)


        } else {
            print("success", dbreference)

        }
    }
```

and I also tried following:-

```
 let key = refArtists.childByAutoId().key

    //creating artist with the given values
    let artist = ["id":key,
                  "latitude": "34234" as String,
                  "longitude": "67657" as String
    ]

    let data = ["data": artist]

    refArtists.child(key!).setValue(data)
```

I am unable to understand why my write operation is unsuccessful.

Edit from comments:

The closure does not get called. I am getting this error :

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any type of error? Does the closure after `setValue` get called?

Comment: Closure does not get called. I am getting this error :- "Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.  Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly"

Comment: This means the connection to your firebase database is not properly set up. More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Comment: The error message hints that your problem is in how you've configured Firebase in your app, and not in the code you shared. Double check against the docs that @bonkyfronk linked. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, edit your question to show how you've configured Firebase in your app.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179186/firebase-completion-listeners-in-swift

Comment: security rules affect your queries.